# How to use unzip in linux terminal SSH?

Tags: command-line, unzip

I just zip a file in my remote server using the command "unzip" in the SSH terminal. It works fine but leaves a new folder called "__MACOSX".

Is there any way to make that the command delete this file after the unzip?

Comment: The only reason that file is there is because it is a normal hidden folder in Mac OSX for all archives created, so its thought to be just a normal folder in the archive..

Comment: `unzip file.zip -d destination_folder` *Apple provides built-in capability to ZIP files in OS X 10.3 and higher, and these files are the result of Apple storing Resource Forks safe manner. You would never see these files running OS X 10.3 or higher, but since Windows and other operating systems do not understand this special form of Resource Forks they will appear as you see them.

Comment: This is related to ubuntu how?

Comment: @Rinzwind: If you unzip a file that was created on a mac running on Ubuntu , this is what you get...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is an extra folder that OSX computers make, they are hidden on OSX.

To exclude the folder from the extraction do:

```
unzip ZipName.zip -x __MACOSX/*
```

Replace "ZipName" with the name of your zip. The important part is matching the folder which is made up of two underscores then MACOSX, /* so it doesn’t extract the hidden file in that folder as well as the folder.